# Drawing on top of the zoomed image

Tags: android, image, ondraw

I need to draw on top of the zoomed image. After zoom out the the image i drawed on top of the zoomed image also need to be zoom out. Anyone can help? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: I could draw the image on top the image  only when it is not zoomed. After the image zoomed i could not draw on top of image

Comment: show your code.

Comment: I took the sample from the below link  http://kyogs.blogspot.in/2013/06/image-with-zoom-and-paint-on-zoomed.html